# Replacing an existing image via the admin interface

Tags: 6, media

Have access to a Drupal 6 admin and attempting to replace a single image via the admin interface. My understanding is that to just replace an existing image that I'll need to access the sever directly. Is there any way to edit (aka replace) an existing image via the admin interface?

Might be worth noting that one reason I want to replace the image, and not just upload a new one is due to the fact that the image is referenced via template, and not in a block, page, etc.

Comment: this depends on where the image is, and how it's used.  Is this image used inside a node?  do you have a file/media manager in use?

Comment: Image is not in a node, it's href is a filepath. Is there a default path to access the file/media manager, and if so, do you know what it is? (Attempted to find it, don't see in in the modules listing; also assume that the manager would assign assets as nodes, so this might not matter anyway.) Might be worth noting that one reason I want to replace the image, and not just upload a new one is due to the fact that the image is referenced via template, and not in a block, page, etc. --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is referenced via a template, there is no (easy) way to replace it via the CMS.  You will need access to the file system, like FTP access.

Otherwise, you could look at finding or writing a module that gave you full access to the filesystem via the Drupal CMS.  This would be.. difficult and dangerous.